# how to capture idle time in iframe jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, web

I have a jquery or javascript that checks if u active on a webpage and it works great.It is currently in my idex.php (page that loads after login) my problem is that this script does not or is not able to capture activity in an iframe.

```
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10; //seconds
        var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

        console.log(IDLE_TIMEOUT);

        document.onclick = function () {
            _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
            console.log("onclick");
        };

        document.onmousemove = function () {
            _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
            console.log("onmousemove");
        };

        document.onkeypress = function () {
            _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
            console.log("onkeypress");
        };

        window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

        function CheckIdleTime() {
            _idleSecondsCounter++;
            var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
            if (oPanel)
                oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
            if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
                alert("Time expired!");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the `iframe` `src` have same origin as parent `document`?

Comment: An iFrame is another window. So if you wish to tract that, I guess you will have to load that script again

Comment: they have the same origin as in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] but thats it @guest271314

Comment: @Rajesh that is wat im trying to avoid. its redundant coding.

Comment: You can export that code to a `utility.js` file and load it in both windows

Comment: Is the `javascript` loaded within the `iframe`?

Comment: @Rajesh do you mean include utility.js in every program? What if i have a million programs already in production? they i will have to go edit all of them..i want to do it index.php because if i do it here i wont have to go change all my programs

Comment: @guest271314 no its not

Comment: Do you have control of the `document` which is loaded at `iframe` `src`?

Comment: @erny just import this script in main(`master template`) and you should be good to do

Comment: @Rajesh wat do you mean (master template) do you mean like the main page where my iframes will be loaded? if thats what you mean then thats my index.php and it does not work. Unless you mean something else